# Is it possible to automatically split a commit for Github compare view?

Tags: git, github, compare, git-commit

At our company code reviews are done in Github compare view by adding comments. Of course you can use difftool or someting. But I'd like to know if there is a way to automatically warn / split a commit when it exceeds [the Github limits](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-limits-for-viewing-content-and-diffs-in-my-repository/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pre-commit [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to prevent large commits. E.g. to check the diff's number of lines, save the following as `[REPO PATH]/.git/hooks/pre-commit` and make it executable (e.g. `chmod +x` on linux):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ $(git diff --cached | wc -l) > 300 ]] && { echo "Commit too long"; exit 1; }
```

or check file size:

```
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/git_XXXXX)
git diff --cached > "$tmp"
[[ $(ls -l "$tmp" | awk '{print $5}') > 10000 ]] && { echo "Commit too large"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: That is actually a decent answer, but it can be improved by telling how to match all the Github limits.

Comment: I also added an example to check file size. Do you have a specific problem with one of the limits?

Comment: it's really about being able to review code within Github, as there is no tool in Git itself to add per line comments. I will test this if it works and if it does you get your well earned accept :)

Comment: Note that I used dummy values. E.g. to use the 1MB limit in your link, you should replace 10000 with `numfmt --from=iec 1M`