# Get file size of a git commit without a tmp file

Tags: linux, git, bash

I've [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33632473/165753), suggesting using git hooks, but frankly, I'M not fully satisfied with the second part, since creating a temporary file just to get the size of the commit looks redundant and ugly. Is there a way to get the size directly? Assume the standard git implementation.

As suggested by @Cyrus, `git diff --cached | wc -c` is a good approximation, but it's encoding dependent.

I also tried process substitution `ls -l <(git diff --cached) | awk '{print $5}'` but that returns 0.

Edit: Based on [@torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35403416/165753) I came up with these two solutions:

`git ls-files --stage | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -L 1 git cat-file -s | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

`git diff --cached | awk -F. '/index/ {print $3}' | xargs -L 1 git cat-file -s | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

The latter also handles new files.

Comment: `git diff --cached | wc -c`?

Comment: I guess that's a good approximation, but it's encoding dependent. I also tried process sub `ls -l <(git diff --cached) | awk '{print $5}'` but that returns 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the size (in bytes) of a git object, use `git cat-file -s revspec`.  For instance:

```
$ git cat-file -s HEAD:Makefile
950
```

Beware that this will show you the object size of a tree:

```
$ git cat-file -t HEAD:
tree
$ git cat-file -s HEAD:
546
```

For a large collection of IDs you might want to use `git cat-file --batch-check` (which, since git 1.8.4, now takes a format argument to select what information to print; see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cat-file.html)).

Comment: Thanks, what would be the refspec of the index?

Comment: I came up with
`git diff --cached | awk -F. '/index/ {print $3}' | xargs -L 1 git cat-file -s | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'` 
but I guess there's a more elegant solution

Comment: The index does not have a refspec, though `:n:path` (where n is one of 0,1,2,3) works if you know a path.  More generally, to read it, use `git ls-files` (in this case `git ls-files --stage` is probably the right method).

Comment: What does `n` stand for?

Comment: For instance, `git rev-parse :0:README` gets the SHA-1 of index slot 0 for file `README`.  If `foo.py` is in the middle of a conflicted merge, `:1:foo.py`, `:2:foo.py`, and `:3:foo.py` get the SHA-1s of the three versions of the file (though if the conflict is delete-vs-modify or create-vs-create there may be fewer than 3 versions).

Answer (score 1):

I think that `git diff --cached --numstat` is basically the main source of the information. For me it's not completely clear what restrictions you'd like to put on a commit but to summarize number of insertions and deletions you could use something like this:

```
git diff --numstat --cached | awk '
   BEGIN { insertions=0; deletions=0; }
   { insertions+=$1; deletions+=$2; }
   END { printf("inserttions=%d, deletions=%d\n", insertions, deletions); }'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant the file size in bytes, as in the output of `ls`